# How to encode or hide iOS app files?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have an iOS App which loads and .txt file from app's root. If i use iFunBox or any iPhone Browsers i can see that .txt file, how can I hide it? I think it's all about security of this file, encode/decode. Please help me. Any advice, source codes, examples. I'm new here. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that it is possible to protect the file any more than what apple already does. Even if you could, I don't think It would really be worth your trouble to do so unless the .txt file is something that you really need to protect.

Comment: thanks. i will use my own server to load file, so... tho way i hope to protect at least from accessing file via iPhone Browser programs

Comment: You're Welcome! Good luck to you.

Comment: @RaduRomanov Keep in mind that anyone can determine the URL you access and then point their web browser to the same URL and download the text file directly.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer:  You can't

The long answer:  No matter what you do, you will end up having a copy of the decrypted contents in memory at some point so a crafty cracker will be able to copy the contents out of memory.  The best you can do is make it not worth their trouble.  This includes using pure C, never storing the contents in one variable (always concat, etc), and encrypting the file with an industry standard encryption like AES-256.  Good luck.

Comment: Depending on the contents/use you can also arrange to "consume" the file as you read it, decrypting just enough for the next "bite".  This works, eg, for video files.